# How do I create if a string includes a text

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I create if a string includes the file being read?

- my **index.js**

```js
if (command == "creategame") {
const lang = args[0]
const gameTypes = args[1]
const allLang = fs.readFileSync('language-supported.txt', 'utf-8')

if(!lang) {
    message.reply("Need language.\nExample: !creategame en character\n\n!creategame <language> <gameType> (ANIMALS/CHARACTER)")
} else {
    fs.readFile('./language-supported.txt', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

// here ima try if the stringMessage includes a text in language-supported.txt
        if(lang.includes(data)) {

            if(!gameTypes) {
                message.reply("Need game types.\nExample: !creategame en character\n\n!creategame <language> <gameType> (ANIMALS/CHARACTER)")
            } else {
                if(gameTypes == "animals" || gameTypes == "character") {
                if(fs.existsSync(gamePath)) {
                    const { language, gameTypes } = require(gamePath);
                    message.reply(`You already create a game, Type: ${gameTypes}, Language: ${language}`)
                } else {
                const conntent = `{ "languageGame": "${lang}", "gameTypes": "${gameTypes}" }`;
                message.reply("game created!")
                fs.writeFileSync(gamePath, conntent);
                }
                } else {
                    message.reply(`The bots only support gametype: **ANIMALS/CHARACTER** not a ${gameTypes}`)
                }
            }   
        } else {
            message.reply("wait i think thats not a Language.")
        }
      });
   
}
}
```

- my **language-supported.txt**

```
af
am
ar
az
be
bg
bn
bs
ca
ceb
co
cs
cy
da
de
el
en
eo
```

- when i run the codes, it always show **wait i think thats not a Language.**
- how do i make if the string/text is included in the list **language-supported.txt**?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is 1 small missing.

`if(lang.includes(data)) {`

should be

`if(data.includes(lang)) {`